# Using a utility interface in Java 7 to enable testing in RCP application?

Tags: java, unit-testing, oop, eclipse-rcp, java-7

I'm having to do an enhancement to an existing RCP application in Java 7. The enhancement is very deep in the class, in a sub sub class. No tests exist for this class.

The sub class extends `JobChangeAdapter` and within the `done()` calls a `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display#syncExec(Runnable)`. We need to make enhancement to the `run()` of the sub sub class which implements `Runnable`.

The enhancement is check for certain conditions and create and launch a dialog so I created a 'utility' interface with two methods in it.

```
boolean isDialogDisplayable(); 
void displayDialog();
```

However, I was told that this is a bad pattern to follow in the code review and that I shouldn't be putting feature behavior into utility classes.

I am wondering as to why is it considered a bad pattern when it enables easy testing?

Comment: Well for one thing that is an example of tight coupling; for another, ease of testing is not how we evaluate a design. The correct place to discuss these kinds of (opinionated) things is in the code review (not with strangers on the internet).

Comment: If ease of testing isn't a criteria to the point where to you can't test a functionality at all then I'm not sure what qualifies as a better evaluation criteria?